# Manage Facebook profiles using API

Tags: php, facebook

I have a php application.I want to manage my facebook profile from my application itself.
1)Logged in to facebook
2)Add comments
3)update my profile
etc.....

is it possible using facebook API.

Help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Companion

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Have a look at this description of the Facebook Graph API, near the bottom is a section on publishing (you do it by sending POST request...):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/

And here is their example for posting to someones wall:

```
curl -F 'access_token=...' \
     -F 'message=Hello, Arjun. I like this new API.' \
     https://graph.facebook.com/arjun/feed
```

And here is an exmaple of posting something to your own feed:

```
curl -F 'access_token=...' \
     -F 'message=I am posting to my own feed. I am awesome.' \
     https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed
```